# Is there a difference between the following two words for chopsticks ? Hashi and Otemoto

Tags: kana

As a Japanese beginner I was familiar with the word Hashi for a while, today I learned that another word for chopsticks is Otemoto.

This word is often written on chopstick wrappers. My guess is that it is more formal than Hashi ?

Comment: おてもと just means chopsticks...

Comment: @Leebo Wow, I didn't know that. Any idea why the kanji has 许(moto) in it ?

Comment: Other words with もと, like あしもと and くちもと can be written with 許 as well. It's one way to write もと.

Comment: +1 for the edited question but please don't do this in future. It is a completely different question and it makes extant comments/answers look weird. This should have been a new question.

Comment: @user3856370 ok I understand, thanks for the heads up

Comment: Related (or duplicate?) https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15134/9831